# How to select reverse range in Bootstrap range slider?

Tags: jquery, html, rangeslider, bootstrap-slider

I have use [Bootstrap range slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) i have 2 questions where i am totally stuck.

> my question is how can i select reverse range like i have a slider with values 1 to 10 then i have to select 9 to 3 how can i do that?

[image]

Here, i have a slider with month range i want to select like oct - feb 
how can i do that???

> And the another question is how can i add labels of my two handles?

Here is my html code,

```
<input id="ex1" type="hidden" data-clear-delay="true" data-provide="slider" data-slider-selection="none" data-slider-value="[0,100]" data-slider-ticks="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]" data-slider-ticks-labels='["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]' data-slider-ticks-positions="[0, 9.09, 18.18, 27.27, 36.36, 45.45, 54.54, 63.63, 72.72, 81.81, 90.90, 100]" data-val="true" name="prefered_travel_period" value="" />
```

and the javascript is,

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#ex1').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return ;
    },
    id: "slider12c",
    labelledby:["min","max"]
 });
});
```

Please help me out of this, thank you in advance.

Comment: What you are asking for is not currently possible in the library. You can add support by: tracking the "current selection" (using the existing range functionality), adding an "invert selection" checkbox (this would "select" the outer range, instead of the inner one).

Comment: Such a great answer. hats of to you but without checkbox its not possible which is :(

Comment: can you please post your answer so that i can mark it as right so it may be help some others.

Answer (score 1):

In order to support selecting month ranges across new year, you could simply make a slider across two generic years, instead of just covering the range of months only over one generic year.

E.g.:

```
<input id="ex1" type="hidden" data-clear-delay="true" data-provide="slider" data-slider-selection="none" data-slider-value="[0,100]" data-slider-ticks="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]" data-slider-ticks-labels='["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan2","Feb2","Mar2","Apr2","May2","Jun2","Jul2","Aug2","Sep2","Oct2","Nov2","Dec2"]' data-slider-ticks-positions="[0, 4.34, 8.69, 13.04, 17.39, 21.73, 26.08, 30.43, 34.78, 39.13, 43.47, 47.82, 52.17, 56.52, 60.86, 65.21, 69.56, 73.91, 78.26, 82.60, 86.95, 91.30, 95.65, 100]" data-val="true" name="prefered_travel_period" value="" />
```

It is always a point of opinion what is "intuitive", but I think this is better than any inverse concept, e.g. like "please select the months you do NOT want to use".

Comment: you mean i have to make two sliders with single handle selection?

Comment: You already have a mechanism to select 3-9 in place, don't you? At least that is what I understood. I only adapted your code quote to demonstrate the 24month concept. If you do the same to whatever you do to select 3-9, you can then select 9-15. With the second value (15) being >12, it indicates that it is a selction across new year and by reducing it by 12 you get the 3 which indicates March.

Comment: Its realy nice concept. i appreciate your answer but i want this with single 12 month slider. giving you a upvote. if it helps some one else.

Comment: That is a kind attitude, towards me and with an eye to the usefulness for others.

Answer (score 0):

You have: `data-slider-ticks` and `data-slider-ticks-labels`

If you want to only display Jan - Jun. You'd have to change it to this:

- `data-slider-ticks="[1,2,3,4,5,6]"`
- `data-slider-ticks-labels='["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun"]'`

Comment: how? i cant understand what are you trying to say

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. Your first question was on how to display less values, wasn't it?

Comment: yes it is but i want to select like a 9 - 2, or like a august - february
how can i?

Comment: I'd write a js-function that reassigns your values. Currently you have  `data-slider-ticks="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]"`. If you want august - february you'd have to change it to this: `data-slider-ticks="[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2,]"`. The numbers aren't important. Important are the `data-slider-ticks-labels`.

Comment: oh my god you misunderstood my question i want 9 to 2 as a value like a selection

Comment: You could add a second slider, which defines the start and end.

Comment: like i would like to select like an 9 to 2 and i want to get this value as [9,2] in my php file and i want selection color also in slider, I would like to select values high to low and low to high also.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's difficult to understand what you want. Do you want something specific?

Comment: see here i have slider with 12 month jan to dec i want to select like oct to march. the selection value returns oct to march.